# Calculate if close date is in the next 3 quarters

Tags: formula, opportunity, closedate

I'm trying to create a formula to return true if the opportunity close date is in the next 3 quarters.
It seems pretty easy, but for some reason I can't find the correct syntax.

Examples:

```
If Close Date = 24/7/17 and Today = 1/1/17: True
If Close Date = 30/11/17 and Today = 1/1/17: False
If Close Date = 11/2/18 and Today = 12/8/17: True
If Close Date = 17/9/18 and Today = 12/10/17: False
```

Comment: Define your definition of quarter. Is it jan -mar, Apr-may and so forth or is it Dec-Feb,Mar-May and so on?. If you look at your second example it falls in one of the next 3 quarters if we consider Jan - March?

Comment: Q1 = Jan till Mar.
I should have said that the current quarter is included in the calculation that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it in the end using 2 formula fields. 
One field calculates the next 3 quarters:

```
CASE (CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3),
1, "Q" & TEXT(CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3)) & " " &  TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) & ", " & "Q" & TEXT(CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3)+1) & " " &  TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) & ", " & "Q" & TEXT(CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3)+2) & " " &  TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())),
2, "Q" & TEXT(CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3)) & " " &  TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) & ", " & "Q" & TEXT(CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3)+1) & " " &  TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) & ", " & "Q" & TEXT(CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3)+2) & " " &  TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())),
3, "Q" & TEXT(CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3)) & " " &  TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) & ", " & "Q" & TEXT(CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3)+1) & " " &  TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) & ", " & "Q" & TEXT(CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3)-2) & " " &  TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())+1),
4, "Q" & TEXT(CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3)) & " " &  TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) & ", " & "Q" & TEXT(CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3)-3) & " " &  TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())+1) & ", " & "Q" & TEXT(CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3)-2) & " " &  TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())+1),
" ")
```

And the second one that calculates the current quarter based on today, in the same format:

```
CONTAINS( Next_3_Quarters__c , "Q" & TEXT(CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/3)) & " " & TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())
```